# human foot detection computer vision

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I have tried matlab CascadeObjectDetector by feeding negative and positive images,but it does not do the job.I want to detect if human standing in the pic is bare feet or not. Object detector should detect bare feet.In negative images I have only given shoes images.If I can do this in opencv somehow,please share that technique too.

[non feet images(negative)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxPo4LdSrdTNZnRtVW96cTlFaEU)

[feet images(positive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxPo4LdSrdTNUWlDLTFuckpZaUE)

feet images folder contain labelingSession.mat which contain info for ROI(region of interest)

```
positiveInstances = labelingSession.ImageSet.ROIBoundingBoxes(1,:);

%Add the image directory to the MATLAB path.

imDir = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','vision','visiondata',...
'feet');

addpath(imDir);
%Specify the foler for negative images.
negativeFolder = fullfile(matlabroot,'toolbox','vision','visiondata',...
'nonfeet');

%Create an imageDatastore object containing negative images.
negativeImages = imageDatastore(negativeFolder);
%Train a cascade object detector called 'stopSignDetector.xml' using HOG          features. NOTE: The command can take several minutes to run.
trainCascadeObjectDetector('shoeDetector.xml',positiveInstances, ...
negativeFolder,'FalseAlarmRate',0.1,'NumCascadeStages',5);
```

Comment: post sample images you've used as positive/negative samples please

Comment: thx. That's not how haar cascade training works. your negatives are quite ok (should be extended to basic images without any feet/shoes present), but your positives must be copped to only have the foot and a little bit of background left (same aspect ratio for each sample). You'll have to decide whether you only want to detect barefoot from a fixed angle (approx) or whether you want a combined classifier of each side. This can influence the quality of the classifier dramatically.

Comment: or did you crop the positice samples implicitly by annotating the areas in the samples.txt file?

Comment: I was using training image labeler from matlab to annotate the region of interest from positive samples and annotation from different angles might not be of same dimension but I want from a fixed angle(front pose).So I guess I will capture enough pictures from  front and learn the classifier on that and extend the negative samples too. where can i get basic images?

Comment: I suggest you actually choose representative photos and put them in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested solely in extracting the image of a foot, then HSV-based skin detection, followed by repetitive dilation should produce better results. See code below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()

{

Mat f=imread("f2.png");//positive
Mat hsv_th;
cvtColor(f,f,CV_BGR2HSV);

inRange(f,Scalar(0,100,0),Scalar(100,255,100),hsv_th);
dilate(hsv_th,hsv_th,cv::Mat());
dilate(hsv_th,hsv_th,cv::Mat());
dilate(hsv_th,hsv_th,cv::Mat());
dilate(hsv_th,hsv_th,cv::Mat());


for(;;)
{
  imshow("fore",f);
  imshow("hsv",hsv_th);

 char c=waitKey(10);
 if(c=='b')//break when 'b' is pressed
      {
         break;
      }
 }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use foot detection as a tool (i.e., you are OK with using 3rd party libraries), then you can take a look to OpenPose, which includes big toe, small toe, heel, and ankle keypoint detection for each feet for all people in the scene. Link:

https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose

My guess is that you can directly apply a SVM detector on top of e.g. SIFT/SURF features applied to each keypoint.